# Animation one image to the next

Tags: iphone, flash, animation

I have a flash file and need to reprogram for iPhone.

The design of the app is a navbar with start buttom and an image view below them.  I have 46 PNL images that I want to show in succession after the start button is clicked.  Each picture will stay on the screen for 5 seconds.

I tried to replicate a code that I got off of YouTube but it did not work.

For the `viewcontroller.h` I used the following code verbatim and was able to link images (I call them `ac`) to the image view and also to establish a link for the start button:

```
{
 IBOutlet UIImageView *ac;
}

-(IBAction)startclick:(id)sender;
```

For the `viewcontroller.m` I used the following concept but I received many syntax warnings:

```
NSarray 
List of 46 png files using @" notation for string
Last png followed by nil 
Then some notation for length that each image appears.
```

If someone could help me out with the `viewcontroller.h` and `viewcontroller.m` to command this sort of animation, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're going to need to be a little more specific about your error messages, otherwise people can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use UIImageView's animationImages property to do this, with your button calling startAnimating and/or stopAnimating:

```
UIImage *frame1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame1.png"];
UIImage *frame2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame2.png"];
UIImage *frame3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame2.png"];
UIImage *frame4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame2.png"];

uiImageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:frame1, frame2, frame3, frame4, nil];
uiImageView.animationDuration = 1.0 // defaults is number of animation images * 1/30th of a second
uiImageView.animationRepeatCount = 5; // default is 0, which repeats indefinitely
[uiImageView startAnimating];

// [uiImageView stopAnimating];
```

If you can't work out the syntax of Objective-C, you're going to struggle to do pretty much anything related to iPhone development.